# Connection between AngularJS and DDBB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, web

Hello (sorry for my bad English). I have a theoretical question. In a web page, there is a direct connection between backend (in my case NodeJS) with the Database (MongoDB). But, I don't know if the frontend (AngularJS) have direct connection with the Database or by NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angularJS should not have a direct connection to your  MongoDB, but It can have a direct connection to your NodeJS App which  has a connection to MongoDB.

WEB --REQUEST----> NodeJS---REQUEST-->MongoDB

WEB <--RESPONSE-----NodeJS----RESPONSE---MongoDB

[Tutorial to get you started](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00)

Answer (score 1):

You would need a step in between that lets Angular's $http services communicate with mongo. NodeJS is one option, especially combined with mongoose and express.

You can find some other options over here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#HttpInterface-RESTInterfaces